What is the average size of each color region in an infinite by infinite randomly colored grid with 3 colors?
You start out with an infinite by infinite grid of squares. Color each one randomly red, green or blue. Each one has a 1 in 3 chance of getting colored red, a 1 in 3 chance of getting colored green, and a 1 in 3 chance of getting colored blue. If 2 squares of the same color are adjacent to each other (not including diagonals), they are part of the same region. What is the average size of the regions?
Of course, we have to deal with the elephant in the room here. There are going to be infinite regions and infinite squares, so it looks like we're dividing infinity by infinity, which we all know is indeterminate. But if you consider the limit as you start with larger and larger grids of squares, what does this average approach as the n by n grid has n grow without bound?
*On a 10 by 10 grid I got the average to be about 2.32558 cells per region. On a 12 by 12 grid I got the average to be about 2.28571 cells per region. On a 15 by 15 grid I got the average to be about 2.36842. On a 18 by 18 grid I got the average to be about 2.72269 cells per region. On a 20 by 20 grid I got the average to be about 2.79720 cells per region. On a 24 by 24 grid I got the average to be about 2.78261 cells per region. On a 30 by 30 grid I got the average to be about 2.74390 cells per region.
**On a 1 by 1 grid the average region size is 1 (obviously). On a 2 by 1 grid the average region size is 4/3  (about 1.33333). On a 1 by 3 grid the average region size is 13/9 (about 1.44444). On a 2 by 2 grid the average region size is 134/81 (about 1.65432). On a 2 by 3 grid the average region size is 2161/1215 (about 1.77860) (this will probably be my last calculation until I find a more efficient method of doing this. There are 729 different ways you could color a 2 by 3 grid with 3 colors, and I'm figuring out how many regions each of these has by hand, and a 2 by 4 grid would have 6561 different ways to color it with 3 colors).
Some more information that might be useful for solving this problem I've already computed:

Probability that a tile has exactly 4 matching neighbors: 1 in 81
Probability that a tile has exactly 3 matching neighbors: 8 in 81
Probability that a tile has exactly 2 matching neighbors: 8 in 27
Probability that a tile has exactly 1 matching neighbor: 32 in 81
Probability that a tile has exactly 0 matching neighbors: 16 in 81

*Using experimental methods.
**Using true probability.

I suggest simulating it to get a sense.

To make at least some of the infinities go away, you can ask "what's the average size of the region containing the square (0, 0)".  (However it is possible that that is a distribution with infinite mean...)

This analysis of cluster size is a key topic in percolation theory, so that is where you should look.  Start with this article on critical exponents.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_critical_exponents

This article also looks like a nice read to approach your problem : https://web.mit.edu/ceder/publications/Percolation.pdf

I would guess somewhere between $2$ and $5.$

This was asked (and not answered) on Math Overflow. The comments might be of interest. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166010/what-is-the-average-size-of-all-continuous-unicolored-areas-in-a-randomly-colore

Cut the problem to 1/3.  On the six cell problem, restrict the lower left cell to be red.  Now you only have 243 possibilities to consider.

Note that it’s certainly the case that the mean size of a region = the mean size of a red region.  So you can calculate exact finite-size results using only $2^{MN}$ states (each square being red or not-red), rather than $3^{MN}$.  That being said, your simulation results on larger grids are interesting… can you put error bars on those?  How many trials did you run for each?  Normally one expects those results to converge to the true one with an error of the form $C/N$, which you can fit.

I am doing all of these simulations by hand because the only programming language I know is MatLab and I'm not even sure if it's possible to code up a program that would run these simulations for me in MatLab.

@Lugo: the average size of a region is definitely not the same as the average size of the region containing a particular square: instead of counting each region just once, you are biasing it by the number of squares it contains. This will inflate the computed average significantly.

@NicoZaczkowski I'm also using MATLAB. I believe the commands you want are regionprops and bwconncomp; these image analysis tools pretty quickly let you calculate areas of connected components for grids (I've been trying out $1000\times 1000$ grids; my not very good laptop analyses one of these in around $1.2$ seconds). I can share the code as an answer if it's helpful, but of course it won't get you an exact result.

Not a total answer, but a long comment.
Michael Lugo suggested a very good method : what's the average size of the region containing the square (0, 0)
In other word : Starting with color Blue in (0,0), expand this area until all neighbors are not Blue.
When we analyze a grid (10x10), (20x20)  etc, all cells at the frontier 'downgrade' the result.
We can simulate, and count the average size of this area, and we can count also the frequency of each size. The average size I obtain is $6.4774$
For small values, the result is consistent with theory ($\dfrac{16}{3^4}$, $\dfrac{256}{3^7}$ , $\dfrac{6144}{3^{10}}$)

With 4 colors, the average is 3.5375 ;
with 5 colors : 2.6129 ;
with 6 colors : 2.1721 ;
with 7 colors : 1.9170 ;
with 8 colors : 1.7515 ;
with 9 colors : 1.6358
Edit : The correct formula is not this one but :
$\dfrac{1975+1171+1040+...}{1975+1171/2+1040/3...}$
With 3 colors : 2.6973
With 4 colors : 1.9392
With 5 colors : 1.6447
With 6 colors : 1.4897
With 7 colors : 1.3943
With 8 colors : 1.3299
With 9 colors : 1.2835

I'm a bit confused. Did you just experiment like I did or use some more mathematical method to obtain the true answer?

Note this is a different problem. If there’s regions of size 1 and 2, the average cluster size is 1.5 but the average size of the cluster an arbitrary cell is in is (1+2+2)/3=1.67.

Nico : it is a simulation, no maths at all. Eric : The more I think about it, the more I consider you are right. The challenge is now to use the result for each size, and find the correct formula to answer the original problem.

Lugo's suggested method is actually very bad. See my comment to the OP.

@TonyK: While the original suggestion is not right (it answers a different question), the “Edit: correct formula” here is exactly right.  It correctly expresses the result in terms of $P_n$, the probability that the region containing $(0,0)$ has size $n$.  These $P_n$ can be found exactly for small $n$ and approximated for larger $n$.

A monocolored region here is a (rookwise) connected set of squares, or a polyomino.
The probability that the monocolored region containing $(0,0)$ is any particular polyomino with size $n$ and perimeter $p$, with a specific node placed at the origin, is $(1/3)^{n-1}(2/3)^p$.  (The perimeter of a polyomino is defined as the number of external squares adjacent to it.)  This is because $n-1$ squares need to have the same color as the origin's, and the $p$ squares on the perimeter need to not have that color (or else the region would be larger).
Let $A_{n,p}$ be the number of distinct polyominoes containing $n$ squares and with perimeter $p$. Counting the $n$ possible choices for the node at the origin, the probability that the region containing $(0,0)$ has size $n$ is exactly
$$
P_n = \sum_{p} \frac{2^p n}{3^{n+p-1}} A_{n,p}.
$$
We can find this exactly for each $n$ just by counting polyominoes, although this task rapidly becomes more difficult as $n$ grows.  It must be that $\sum_n P_n = 1$; and the expected size of the monocolored region containing the origin is just $\sum_n n P_n$.  [We're only identifying regions related through translation, not rotation or reflection, so we're counting fixed polyominoes, allowing holes.  The total number of fixed polyominoes with $n$ squares -- our $\sum_p A_{n,p}$ -- is known at least to $n=56$ (OEIS A001168), which will be a useful check on our work.]
But, as pointed out in comments on another answer, this quantity is not the same as the one being asked for.  If we want the expected size of any region (not the one containing a particular site, which is strongly biased toward being larger than average), it's slightly more complicated.  Let's choose one particular square in each polyomino; call it the key square.  (It doesn't matter how we do this; for instance, we could always take the topmost square in the leftmost column.)  Then the density of key squares on an infinite grid is the probability that any particular point (say, the origin) is a key square:
$$
\rho = \sum_{n}\frac{1}{n}P_n.
$$
And it should be clear that the expected size of a random region is just $1/\rho$.  Alternately, the expected size of a random region is the expected size of the region containing $(0,0)$ conditional on the fact that $(0,0)$ is the key square of that region.  It's not hard to show, using $\sum_n P_n=1$, that this is the same quantity; but when we truncate the sums at a finite $n$ (as we must), it represents a different approximation.  So, summarizing, we have two distinct quantities we can approximate using the $A_{n,p}$, and we have two distinct approximations for the latter.  $E_1$ is the expected size of the region containing $(0,0)$, and $E_2$ is the expected size of a randomly chosen region.
$$
E_1 = \sum_{n} n P_n; \qquad E_2 =\frac{1}{\sum_n P_n / n} = \frac{\sum_{n} P_n}{\sum_{n} P_n / n}.
$$
Here are the values of the $A_{n,p}$ for smallish $n$:
$$
\begin{array} {|l|r|}
\hline
A_{n,p} & p=p_0 & p_0+1 & +2 & +3 & +4 & +5 & +6 & +7 & +8 & \ldots & \Sigma_p A_{n,p} \\
\hline
n=1, p_0=4 & 1 &  &  &  &  & & & & & \ldots & 1 \\
\hline
n=2, p_0=6 & 2 &  &  &  &  & & & & & \ldots & 2 \\
\hline
n=3, p_0=7 & 4 & 2 &  &  &  & & & & & \ldots & 6 \\
\hline
n=4, p_0=8 & 9 & 8 & 2 &  &  & & & & & \ldots & 19 \\
\hline
n=5, p_0=8 & 1 & 20 & 28  & 12 & 2 & & & & & \ldots & 63 \\
\hline
n=6, p_0=9 & 4 & 54 & 80 & 60 & 16 & 2 & & & & \ldots & 216 \\
\hline
n=7, p_0=10 & 22 & 136 & 252 & 228 & 100 & 20 & 2 & & & \ldots & 760 \\
\hline
n=8, p_0=10 & 4 & 80 & 388 & 777 & 818 & 480 & 152 & 24 & 2 & \ldots & 2725 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
(I've calculated them through $n=13$.)  Now, we can use these values to form a sequence of increasingly good estimates of the quantities we're interested in:
$$
\begin{array} {|l|r|}
\hline
N & P_N/N & \sum_{n=1}^{N}P_n/n & \sum_{n=1}^{N}P_n & \sum_{n=1}^{N}nP_n \\
\hline
1 & 16/81 & 0.197531 & 0.197531 & 0.197531 \\
\hline
2 & 128/2187 & 0.256059 & 0.314586 & 0.431642 \\
\hline
3 & 2048/59049 & 0.290742 & 0.418635 & 0.743789 \\
\hline
4 & 35072/1594323 & 0.312740 & 0.506628 & 1.09576 \\
\hline
5 & 1.480215 \times 10^{-2} & 0.327542 & 0.580638 & 1.46581 \\
\hline
6 & 1.035752 \times 10^{-2} & 0.337899 & 0.642783 & 1.83868 \\
\hline
7 & 7.488131 \times 10^{-3} & 0.345387 & 0.695200 & 2.20560 \\
\hline
8 & 5.547522 \times 10^{-3} & 0.350935 & 0.739581 & 2.56064 \\
\hline
9 & 4.186804 \times 10^{-3} & 0.355122 & 0.777262 & 2.89977 \\
\hline
10 & 3.205618 \times 10^{-3} & 0.358327 & 0.809318 & 3.22034 \\
\hline
11 & 2.483296 \times 10^{-3} & 0.360811 & 0.836634 & 3.52081 \\
\hline
12 & 1.942496 \times 10^{-3} & 0.362753 & 0.859944 & 3.80053 \\
\hline
13 & 1.531889 \times 10^{-3} & 0.364285 & 0.879859 & 4.05942 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
This gives us a range of about $2.415$ (a lower bound: the second column divided by the first) to $2.745$ (an upper bound: the inverse of the first column) for the desired quantity, with steady convergence (the latter estimate is converging much faster).  We can accelerate the convergence by noting that $P_n$, in particular, is decaying very close to exponentially (as the ratio between successive terms is nearly constant).  If we propose $P_n = \lambda^{n-13} P_{13} $ for $n\ge 13$, and demand that $\sum_{n}P_n = \sum_{n=1}^{12}P_n + P_{13} / (1-\lambda)=1$, we find $\lambda = 0.857810$.
Using this extrapolated form for large $n$ (and the exact values for small $n$) gives us $E_2 = 1/\rho \approx 2.697$, and $E_1 \approx 6.466$.  Both of these are fully consistent with the results from the other answer (differing primarily by the fact that only the exact values for small $n$ are used here).

You are computing the wrong average $-$ see my comment to the OP.

I'd like to know the exact value, not just a decimal approximation.

@TonyK: I computed both.  The value requested by the OP (the average size of a randomly chosen region) is $1/\rho$, approximately $2.697$.

@NicoZaczkowski: I suspect the exact value isn't going to be forthcoming, except in terms of the sum of an infinite series (like the one I  describe here).

For each $N$, the probability that the area around $(0,0)$ has an area of size $N$ can be calculated, with an exact formula (generic formula, same formula, no matter the number of colors) ; it is long and it needs to be very methodic. For example, for size 1, the formula is $\frac{c-1}{c})^4$ where $c$ is the number of colors. Problem, each new value $N$ is a new problem to solve, it is very long. Maybe this sequence exists for some specific values $c$ ?

@Lourran: Right; this same analysis yields the result for any number of colors.  $P_n(x)=\sum_p x^{n-1}(1-x)^p A_{n,p}$ is a polynomial in $x$ for each value of $n$.  For instance, $P_1(x)=(1-x)^4$.  Substituting $x=1/c$ gives the desired probability for $c$ colors.  But since $A_{n,p}$ doesn't have a known closed form, it's doesn't seem likely that, say, $\sum_{n} n P_n(x)$ does either.
